# Styling using mi-style column from mapinfo

Tags: qgis, postgis, mapinfo, style

I have uploaded some MapInfo tables into postgis including the mi-style column using EasyLoader; I have had to rename all columns including both mi-style and sp-geometry columns to lowercase, including the mapinfo_mapcatalog, otherwise Oracle (which also needs to see this data) couldn't load the tables.

I would like to style this data using the original MapInfo styles. I have found a github link (https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator/wiki/Using-MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator.) that allows me to create a qlr from the MapInfo table but is there a way to use the mi-style column in postgis to create the correct entry in public.layer-styles which allows me to keep the styles within the Postgis database which I can then reference?